# How to create or get visio instance (visio is installed on app-v)?

Tags: c#, visio, appv

I have Visio installed on app-v, the Microsoft tools for application virtualization. I run visio on my local machine, it works pretty well. But when writing a c# code on my local machine to get or create a Visio application like below :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application application = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Visio.Application");
```

I got the error:

> Operation not available (Exception de HRESULT : 0x800401E3 (MK_E_UNAVAILABLE))

I first lunch Visio, then my c# code so i'm sure that Visio is in running.
Of course i understand the error but how can i get or create Visio in such scenario?

Comment: What error do you get?  How are you creating a Visio application?  You need to provide more detail.

Comment: I added more details about the issue.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).